# Почему элементы пропадают после анимации ReactCSSTransitionGroup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, анимация, reactcsstransitiongroup

Имеется такой компонент, почему после срабатывания анимации элементы пропадают?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import newid from 'utils/newid';

import WorkItem from '../WorkItem';

class PortfolioSectionPanel extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showWorks: false,
            works: [
                {
                    type: 'Веб-разработка',
                    link: 'some',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Продвижение',
                    link: 'some1',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Скриптинг',
                    link: 'some',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Веб-дизайн',
                    link: 'some1',
                },
                {
                    type: 'Копирайтинг',
                    link: 'some',
                }
            ]
        }

        this.showWorks = () => {
            this.setState({
                showWorks: !this.state.showWorks,
            })
        }

    }
    
    render() {

        let workItems;

        if(this.state.showWorks) {
            let {works} = this.state;

            const angleRad = 360 / works.length * 0.017; //Частота кругов в радианах
            const bg = document.getElementById('portfolio-panel-disk');
            let radius;
            if(bg) {
                radius = parseInt(getComputedStyle(bg).width) / 2;
            }

            workItems = works.map((currentValue, index) => {
                return <WorkItem 
                        type={currentValue.type} 
                        link={currentValue.link} 
                        key={newid()} 
                        leftOffset={radius - radius * Math.cos(angleRad * index)}
                        topOffset={radius - radius * Math.sin(angleRad * index)}  />
            })
        } else {
            workItems = null;
        }
   
        return(

            <div className='portfolio-panel' id='porfolioPanel' ref={this.props.link}>
                <div className='portfolio-panel-background' ref={this.props.linkCircle} onTransitionEnd={this.showWorks} >
                    <div className='portfolio-panel-disk' id='portfolio-panel-disk'>
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                        transitionName='work-item'
                        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                            {workItems}
                        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
    

export default PortfolioSectionPanel;
```

CSS самих синих кругов, т.е. `WorkItems`

```css
.work-item {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: @maxColor;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: @whiteColor;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;

    &__type {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    &-enter {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    &-enter-active {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &-leave {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    &-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

[Вот как происходит в самом проекте](https://wmpics.pics/di-EUJC.gif)

Comment: У вас ошибка в коде и он не открывается

Comment: У Вас есть кастомный css? похоже на `opacity:0`

Comment: @Alt_F4, это не воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi Тогда можно было просто так поставить - без сниппетов. Хотя я всё равно не смогу дать ответ на него))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, прикрепил CSS

Comment: поменяйте для проверки opacity 0 на 1 в leave-active

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, суть в том, что этих элементов даже в DOM нет, они просто удаляются по какой-то причине

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий формат:

```
<Transition timeout={300} unmountOnExit={true}>
    {state => <div className={`work-item ${state}`}></div>}
</Transition >
```

`timeout` - скорость анимации в ms должна совпадать с тем что вы пишите в css;

`unmountOnExit` - отвечает за рендеринг в DOM если true то элемента в DOM не будет.

`state` - нужен для передачи состояния анимации в элемент.